# What should happen when sending analogWrite signal to a non-PWM pin?

Tags: pwm, analogwrite

I'm a very new to Arduino and any electrical engineering, I'm learning through some Youtube tutorials.

Based on my understanding though, sending analog signals to a non-PWM pin would just check for a threshold and send either LOW or HIGH, as opposed to being able to send variable voltages to a PWM pin.

**BUT** ... that's not what I'm seeing in practice...

Using Arduino UNO, I made a little project, for changing a blue LED's brightness. At first I did it through a PWM pin (pin 9) and it worked flawlessly. But then I tried seeing what would happen in a non-PWM pin (pin 8), you know cause you learn by trying and experimenting. So I switched to a non-PWM pin and ... it works the same exact way ...

I can change the brightness of the LED **5 different levels** ... using analogWrite ... to a non-PWM pin ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess your code switches the pin by calling analogWrite repeatedly. add your test sketch to the question

Comment: You might want to check the output signal with an oscilloscope. Perhaps they enhanced their library to use a timer and its interrupt to generate PWM by software.

Comment: I would also guess that you are just doing the dimming in code somehow. I just tested this with an Arduino Nano and the latest Arduino AVR core (1.8.6) and it is switching exactly between 2 levels: HIGH and LOW. And the code in wiring_analog.c is reflecting that. Please show us the code with which you got those 5 levels.

Comment: You need to show your code. Please edit the question and do that. *I can change the brightness of the LED 5 different levels ... using analogWrite ... to a non-PWM pin ...* . Show us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my understanding though, sending analog signals to a non-PWM pin would just check for a threshold and send either LOW or HIGH, as opposed to being able to send variable voltages to a PWM pin.

On the Uno you do not send analog signals anywhere. The PWM pins are merely digital outputs which turn on and off rapidly at a frequency and duty cycle that you specify.

You can, therefore, do the same thing to non-PWM pins by sending HIGH/LOW at a variable rate.

To comment more on why your code appears to be "working" we would need to see it.

---

> What is the point of PWM pins if its also possible to send variable high/low signals to non-PWM pins?

Well, the PWM pins output high/low signals asynchronously. That is, without code having to do it. So, if you set up a timer (which is connected to the PWM pins) to output 100kHz then it will do that, regardless of what the code is doing at the time. You might be calculating prime numbers, but the hardware timers will mindlessly toggle that PWM pin on and off at the specified frequency.

If you try to make your own PWM in code, then the code has to do that **and nothing else** if it is going to output a consistent signal.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the response. Yes I understand that concept of what PWM pins do by rapidly sending digital signals. My question was mostly theoretical stuff that's why I didn't show code. Based on your answer it is possible to also send variable signals (high/low) to a non-PWM pin, which is what had me confused. What is the point of PWM pins if its also possible to send variable high/low signals to non-PWM pins? 
(This is the only part that has me confused about that)

Comment: @BlueStarXD See updated answer. In a lot of coding there is the easy way and the hard way. Manually doing PWM through code is the hard way.

Comment: I've got [a page about the hardware timers](https://www.gammon.com.au/timers) which might help your understanding.